# ajax with function callback doesn´t work

Tags: ajax, post, callback

I have the following `main ajax function`, which I want to use for `multiple posts` later, that´s why it has a `callback function as an argument`. However something must be wrong in this code as it `does not post any data` to the text file but I don´t get `any error` in the console. Simply nothing happens when I `click the button`.

```
  function postAjax( sUrl , frmData, callback ){
              var ajax = new XMLHttpRequest();
              ajax.onreadystatechange = function() {
                if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
                    var ajDataFromServer = JSON.parse(this.responseText);
                    callback( ajDataFromServer );
                }
            }           
              ajax.open( "POST", sUrl , true );
              var jFrm = new FormData( frmData );
              ajax.send( jFrm )                 
            }

  // DO the SIGNUP, POST data to the SERVER with AJAX

  // GLOBAL ARRAY for storing any USER DATA from the SERVER
  var ajDataFromServer = [];

  btnSignupForm.addEventListener("click", postAjax("api_signup_users.php", frmSignup, signupUser));

  function signupUser(ajDataFromServer) {

              if ( ajDataFromServer.status == "ok" ) {

                  //console.log( "SIGNUP SUCCESFULL" );
                  pageLogin.style.display = "flex";
                  pageSignup.style.display = "none";
                  lblLoginErrorMessage.innerHTML = "";
                  var sSignupSuccesMessage = "Account succesfully created - Signup please";
                  var sSignupSuccesMessage = sSignupSuccesMessage.fontcolor( "#549839" );
                  lblLoginErrorMessage.insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend', sSignupSuccesMessage);

              } else {

                  //console.log( "SIGNUP FAIL - TRY AGAIN" );
                  pageViewProducts.style.display = "none";
                  pageSignup.style.display = "flex";
                  lblSignupErrorMessage.innerHTML = "";
                  var sSignupErrorMessage = "Signup Failed - Try again";
                  lblSignupErrorMessage.insertAdjacentHTML( 'beforeend', sSignupErrorMessage );

              }
          }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way you are binding to the button click is incorrect. 
see https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener for some examples.

Basically, the current way will immediately invoke the function, then return the result to be bound on click. 
What you want is to bind to, is a **reference** to the function so that it can be invoked each time the button is clicked.

I've put together a simplified jsfiddle here to demonstrate the difference
https://jsfiddle.net/fdhtmj65/

you'll notice that because the function is executed immediately on the binding to the fail button, you'll get an alert immediately on page load, because the function was executed during the addEventListener.

Your addEventListener line should look something more like this

```
btnSignupForm.addEventListener("click", function()
    {
        postAjax("api_signup_users.php", frmSignup, signupUser)
    });
```